# Connecting to telnet servers with Python

Tags: python, telnet, telnetlib

I want to interactively connect to a telnet server in Python and be able to both read and write text to the server. I am trying the following code to connect:

```
import telnetlib
host = telnetlib.Telnet("mud.accursed-lands.com",8000)
host.read_very_eager()
```

But when I do this nothing happends. If I wrap the `host.read_very_eager()` in print then I get `b''`, which I think represents an empty bit.

How can I interactively connect to this server?

Comment: `b` is actually a [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#binaryseq) class.

Comment: And you can connect and get text back immediately if you connect manually to the MUD, with the *standard* telnet client?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing a telnet session in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19845525/accessing-a-telnet-session-in-python)

Comment: By "interactively", do you refer to the interaction between your Python script and the mud server? Or do you refer to the interaction between your human user and the mud server?

Comment: Between human user and mud server

Comment: Then the duplicate I mentioned won't help you. It describes how to get your Python program to interact with a telnet server.

Comment: By the way, your code snippet produces an expected output. `.read_very_eager()` returns only whatever data has already been received, with no waiting. By the time you have called `.read_very_eager()`, nothing has yet been received. To demonstrate this, add "time.sleep(1)" before the call to `.read_very_eager()`.

Comment: How do you make it so you are receiving a constant stream of input? It's hard to believe what I am doing is as difficult as it is. I mean,  I essentially just want to achieve what is easily doable in terminal by typeing "telnet host:port", but I want to do it in Python instead of in terminal.

Comment: How is your program interacting with the human user? Graphically? Through `print()`/`raw_input()`?

Comment: Yeah, print()/raw_input()

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me as well, getting the expected output